# UDP buffering and interpolation in a multiplayer game

Tags: java, libgdx, real-time, multiplayer, kryonet

We're developing a fairly simple 2D multiplayer platform shooter and we've run in to some problems with constructing an UDP buffer for the states of world entities(players, bullets, etc.). Currently we are sending the location (x, y) of each game entity along with its x and y velocity 30times/s. This gives us a rather smooth experience as long as no packets are lost. However, if a packet is lost we get jittering. To avoid this we want to use interpolation between the last known positions.

We're using Libgdx for the game development and our net services are done using the kryonet library.

The questions are:

1. How do you construct a simple and reliable UDP buffer? We're tried by using the time difference between send time and arrival time in order to delay the execution of the packets on the receiving end by 50ms. But either we did that wrong or the interpolation itself was flawed because the jittering just got worse.
2. How to properly linearly interpolate travel tracks?

The code below is a snippet of our interpolation methods.

```
//Called every time a UDP packet has arrived adding it to the queue.
public void addEntityPacket(EntityPacket pkt){
    entityStates.add(pkt);
}

//Called each Gdx update (60times/s). Linearly interpolates (lerp)
//the entity with the next entityState in queue using getAlpha().
public void updateEntityState(){
    if (entityStates.size > 0) {
        EntityPacket pkt = entityStates.pop();
        currentPos.set(body.getPosition()); // sets currentPos to the entitys current position.
        targetPos.set(pkt.xp, pkt.yp); // sets the targeted to the next state position retrieved from the queue.
        interpolatedPos.set(currentPos).lerp(targetPos, getAlpha()); // calculates the linear interpolation using getAlpha().
        body.setTransform(interpolatedPos, 0); // Moves the entity to the calculated position
        body.setLinearVelocity(pkt.xf, pkt.yf); // Sets the velocity
    }
}

//Called when calculating interpolation.
public float getAlpha(){
    long now = TimeUtils.millis(); // current time
    float alpha = (now - lastUpdateTime) / 30f; // time difference divided by update frequency.
    lastUpdateTime = now;
    return MathUtils.clamp(alpha, 0f, 1.0f); // We do not want the alpha to be less than 0 or greater than 1 or the interpolation will behave strangely.
}
```